# List of Taylor Swift Songs With Unconventional Time Signatures

Tags: pop, taylor-swift

What Taylor Swift songs  use unconventional time signatures like 10/8 (I know “evermore” and “closure” do, but are there others?). By unconventional I mean time signatures not widely used that might be a little difficult at first to adjust to.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Aaron Dessner in an interview with Rolling Stone](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-features/aaron-dessner-interview-taylor-swift-evermore-1105853/), "[Tolerate it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukxEKY_7MOc)" is in 10/8, and "[Closure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIFnKqIeEdY)" is in 5/4 (which can sound like 10/8).

Comment: These seem specific to one album, Evermore- not counting the latest (which just came out) I wonder if there's any others.  The two albums (Folklore and Evermore)  around that time sounded a wee bit more experimental to me

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, I agree. It's also worth noting that both these examples were co-written by Aaron Dessner, who seems to enjoy unconventional time signatures and hadn't collaborated with Taylor Swift before 2020. It'd be interesting to see if there are any examples that weren't co-written by him.